# Error in menuSubItem shiny r: Error in leaflet::JS(callback) : The arguments for JS() must be a character vector

Tags: r, shiny, r-leaflet

Im struggling on creating a basic shiny app because of an error. I have found the error, witch is the menuSubItem where on any simple task the console sends:

Error in leaflet::JS(callback) :
The arguments for JS() must be a character vector

I´ll put a basic code here

I have tried everything and searched online but there is no information about this error

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  ## Sidebar content
  dashboardSidebar(
    sidebarMenu(
      menuItem("Widgets", tabName = "widgets", icon = icon("globe"),
               menuSubItem("Widget1", tabName = "widget1", icon = icon("blind")), 
               menuSubItem("Widget2", tabName = "widget2", icon = icon("blind")))
    )
  ),
  ## Body content
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widget1", h2("Widgets1 tab content")),
      # Second tab content
      tabItem(tabName = "widget2", h2("Widgets2 tab content"))
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){}
shinyApp(ui, server)

How can i fix this?
```

Comment: I get no error with this.

Comment: Something is missing from your code. You aren't even loading `leaflet`